# How to merge two DataFrames that have different lengths and index of one is a subset of the other but their datatypes are different?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to merge these two DataFrames.

```
+-------------------------------------+--+
|                df1:                 |  |
+-------------------------------------+--+
| Date           Temperature     Load |  |
| 01-01-2019      25              400 |  |
| 02-01-2019      32              487 |  |
| 03-01-2019      35              501 |  |
| 04-01-2019      28              457 |  |
| '               '               '   |  |
| '               '               '   |  |
| '               '               '   |  |
| 31-12-2019      22              385 |  |
+-------------------------------------+--+
```

```
+----------------------------------+
|               df2:               |
+----------------------------------+
| Date          Holiday            |
| 02-03-2019    Mahashivratri      |
| 14-04-2019    Good Friday        |
| 18-09-2019    Ganesh Chaturthi   |
| '               '                |
| '               '                |
| 25-12-2019    Christmas          |
+----------------------------------+
```

I tried the merge method.

```
final = df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
```

I also tried the join method similarly.

```
final = df1.join(df2, on='Date', how='left')
```

In both cases, the 'Holiday' column did get appended to df1, but all its values were NaN.

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                      final:                       |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Date           Temperature     Load     Holiday |
| 01-01-2019      25              400     NaN     |
| 02-01-2019      32              487     Nan     |
| '               '               '       '       |
| '               '               '       '       |
| 02-03-2019      33              510     NaN     |
| '               '               '       '       |
| '               '               '       '       |
| 31-12-2019      22              385     NaN     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

What I wanted to achieve was this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                        final:                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Date           Temperature     Load     Holiday       |
| 01-01-2019      25              400     NaN           |
| 02-01-2019      32              487     Nan           |
| '               '               '       '             |
| '               '               '       '             |
| 02-03-2019      33              510     Mahashivratri |
| '               '               '       '             |
| '               '               '       '             |
| 31-12-2019      22              385     NaN           |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `merge` command is correct and works perfectly:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-01-2019', '02-03-2019'], 'Temperature': [25,32], 'Load': [400, 501]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['02-03-2019', '14-04-2019'], 'Holiday': ['Mahashivratri', 'Good Friday']})
df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left')
```

It gives the desired result:

```
         Date  Temperature  Load        Holiday
0  01-01-2019           25   400            NaN
1  02-03-2019           32   501  Mahashivratri
```

The problem is probably with the dtype of your `Date` column.  You haven't shown us what that is, but that's where you need to look, because the rest is correct.

Next time please post a self-contained runnable example program, as I did above.  Had you done that here you probably would have solved your problem on your own, because your data is actually not what you think it is.  I bet one of your Date columns has `datetime` dtype and one has `object` dtype.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. You were right. The 'Date' column in df1 was of datetime type and the 'Date' column in df2 was object. So, I did df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) and the merge command worked this time.

Comment: @NitinSingh: You're welcome.  If this solved your problem you can "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to SO.